# Symmetry group of the geometric realization of a simplicial complex

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Question: Given $\Delta$ an abstract simplicial complex, can one find a geometric realization of $\Delta$ whose symmetry group is isomorphic to $Aut(\Delta)$?

Relevant definitions:

Let $\Delta$ an abstract simplicial complex on the vertex set $V$.

An automorphism of $\Delta$ is a bijection $f:V \to V$ whose induced map on the whole complex sends elements of $\Delta$ to elements of $\Delta$. These automprhisms form a group $Aut(\Delta)$.

A geometric realization of $\Delta$ is a (geometric) simplicial complex whose underlying set is $\Delta$.

For any geometric simplicial complex embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ one can define its symmetry group as 
the set of all isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that map the complex to itself.
$\ $

Thanks!

Comment: Could you define more specific of geometric realization?

Comment: I don't really know this subject, but here's a guess. Can you simply put the vertices at the corners of a $(|V|-1)$-simplex?

Comment: apt1002's suggestion solves the problem.

Comment: Ah I see, that would indeed work, thanks!

Comment: @apt1002 You should definitely write this up as an answer so that this question can be marked as answered! I would upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the vertices at the corners of a $(|V|−1)$-simplex.